# dynamicaly change the grid pattern on bootstrap by a click

Tags: jquery, html, css

//I am trying to dynamically change the grid layout of my design by a button click,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="first">
            <div class="col-md-2">Steppers</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                some content
                <button id="change">Change Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//On button click, this layout should change and split in to two and the new dynamic content should come up there.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="first">
            <div class="col-md-2">Steppers</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                some content
                <button id="change">Change Button</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="second">some new dynamic content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some jQuery that does just that:

```
$("#change").on("click", function() {
    $(".col-md-6.offset-md-3").removeClass("offset-md-3").children("row").addClass("first").removeClass("row");
    $(".row").append(`<div class="col-md-6"><div class="second">some new dynamic content here</div></div>`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a two methods to achieve what you want.

- One with append code into the HTML
- Two with hide and show HTML

```js
  $( "#container" ).hide();

$( "#change" ).click(function() {
  $( "#container" ).append( "<div class=\"col-md-6\"> <div class=\"second\">some new dynamic content here</div></div>");
});

$( "#change2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#container" ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="first">
            <div class="col-md-2">Steppers</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                some content
                <button id="change">Change Button</button>
                  <button id="change2">Change Method2</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
<div class="col-md-6"> <div class="second">some new dynamic content here</div></div>
</div>
```